# How can I put an object inside an array with different properties

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks

So I'm trying to make an array with different properties for each day of the week.

I have this array:

```
const [fullData, setFullData] = useState([{index:-1,exercise:""}])
```

So when user clicks on Monday for instance, I have a bunch of exercises for him to choose. For each exercise I want to put the index of the weekday( I already have this in my code) lets say 1 and the exercises that he chose.

It would end up with something like:

```
[{index:1,exercise:"exercise1"},{index:1,exercise:"exercise2"}]
```

I'm not really sure how to do this cause I have the exercises already in an array:

```
const [exerciseValues, setExerciseValues] = useState([]);
```

And my weekday is just a regular variable

```
  let selectedWeekday_Index:number;
```

I tried a bunch of examples listed in stackoverflow already but I could implement it to my code, can anybody help me out? My last try ended up with this code - that does not work. If anyone needs more details to understand just ask me and I will update the question with it.

```
 const acceptExercises = () => {
    let selectedElements = [...exerciseValues]
    let savedData = [...fullData]
    
    selectedElements.forEach(element => {
      let copyData=savedData.map(item=>({
        [item.exercise]:element,
        [item.index]:selectedWeekday_Index
      }))
      setFullData(copyData)
    });
   }
```

Comment: It seems like you want to keep the two arrays in sync. While this is possible, I'd recommend keeping one state (only the full data) as an object like `{ [index]: [...exercises] }` like `{ "1": ["exercise1", "exercise2"], "2": ["exercise3", "exercise4"] }`. Also consider `useReducer`.

Comment: I see. That's definitely a better way. I will try it out, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also recommend saving your data in a different way like *@iz_* mentioned.

But If you still want to do it that way you can make use of this implementation of setting your `fullData`:

```
  const acceptExercises = () => {
    setFullData((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      ...exerciseValues.map((exercise) => ({
        index: selectedWeekday_Index,
        exercise: exercise,
      })),
    ]);
  };
```

First we copy the previous values via `prev`, then we map through the `exerciseValues` and get a list of `exercises` with the correct week index, which we spread and add to the `fullData`.

Comment: I will change the way my data is structured. May I ask a question about your implementation though.  Prev is receiving the previous version of exercise values and adding the new version too by mapping the exerciseValues?

Comment: Exactly. That's why I like react, code can be written so short